# How to get a transparent WebBrowser/Page

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser, transparent

I have to watch one server page for changes. This page has around 10 tables. Everyday I have to check the new page against the old one to find out is there any number changed in these tables. So, instead of Checking them one by one, I am trying to see them as transparent pages. So I can open the old Page in one window, and the other in another window. Then compare them by superimposing one over the other. So All I want is I want to see the desktop through the browser. But I couldn't find any page which describes it clearly. Google brings this [page](http://lifehacker.com/5927299/the-transparent-desktop) . But this also not helpful. Can anybody guide me on this?

Note: The server page is accessible only in IE 10 and above or google chrome. The OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your operating system, but these two programs might help: 
Windows: http://www.lukepaynesoftware.com/projects/peek-through/

Mac OS: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22237/afloat

Comment: Nice solution. I am checking it.

Comment: But sometime lukepayne also considers the taskbar which results in non responding taskbar. And the very main bug is it is not bringing back the old state when it got closed using task manager.